# Google admob rewarded ads won't change size in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, admob

I'm using admob's rewarded ads in swiftui and I can't get the ads to change size. I'm not sure if it's not allowed but I only want to change the frame because the timer on the ad is being blocked by the top of my phone.

```
struct RewardedAd: UIViewRepresentable{
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RewardedAdUIView {
        let adView = RewardedAdUIView()
        let request = GADRequest()
        GADRewardedAd.load(withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313", request: request) {  ad, error in
            if let error = error{
                print("Failed to load reward ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            adView.rewardedAd = ad
            adView.rewardedAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = context.coordinator
        }
        return adView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: RewardedAdUIView, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate{
        
    }
    
    class RewardedAdUIView: UIView{
        var rewardedAd : GADRewardedAd?{
            didSet{
                showRewardedAd()
            }
        }
        
         init(){
             super.init(frame: .zero)
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        func showRewardedAd(){
            if rewardedAd != nil{
                rewardedAd!.present(fromRootViewController: UIApplication.shared.getRootViewController()) { [weak self] in
                    let reward = self?.rewardedAd?.adReward
                    print("\(reward?.type), \(reward?.amount)")
                }
            }
            else{
                print("Ad wasn't ready")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIApplication{
    func getRootViewController() -> UIViewController{
        guard let screen = self.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else{
            return .init()
        }
        
        guard let root = screen.windows.first?.rootViewController else{
            return .init()
        }
        
        return root
    }
}
```

then i'm calling it in my ContentView.

I tried using .frame, .offset, .ignoresSafeArea (with and without), .navigationBarHidden (true and false). I'm pretty sure it's something simple but I figured I'd just ask anyway.